# Why does my buffer take more bytes than allowed?

Tags: c++, file, iostream

I set the buffer of my `stringstream` to a 5 byte buffer. Only when I call `sputn` it can read in more characters than I want. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    char buf[5];

    ss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buf, sizeof buf);
    ss.rdbuf()->sputn("hello world", 12);

    std::cout << ss.rdbuf(); // prints "Hello world"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to C. There is nothing in C to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot. This means that c++ does not do bounds checking for you.

Comment: @andre: This isn't raw array access though, this is a member of `std::basic_ostream`.  It really shouldn't be writing passed the end of the array.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't think `sputn` has any guaranty it will not write beyond the buffer.

Comment: @andre: sortof.  `If the output sequence write position is not available, returns overflow(traits::to_int_-type(c)).`  On the other hand, it doesn't appear that `pubsetbuf` is required to remember how bit it's buffer is, so it would claim the write position is _always_ available >.<

Comment: @MemyselfandI, what compiler are you using?  I wonder what compilers behave rationally in this situation...

Comment: @MooingDuck I compiled this in Ideone (I believe that would be gcc 4.7.2)

Comment: When I checked MSVC2008, it _appears_ to ignore the call to `pubsetbuf` altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that `pubsetbuf` is implementation defined. On gcc it sets a new buffer, but for example on MSVC nothing happens (it calls the base class `setbuf` which does nothing).

Now, as mentioned [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sputn), `sputn` calls [overflow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow) (or achieves the effect of calling it by some other means):

> If the put area becomes full (pptr() == epptr()), this function may
>   call overflow(), or achieve the effect of calling overflow() by some
>   other, unspecified, means.

Now according to the docs for [overflow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/overflow):

> Ensures that there is space at the put area for at least one character
>   by saving some initial subsequence of characters starting at pbase()
>   to the output sequence and updating the pointers to the output area
>   (if needed). If ch is not traits::eof() (i.e. traits::eq_int_type(c,
>   traits::eof()) != true), it is either put to the output area or
>   directly saved to the output sequence.
>
> The function may update pptr, epptr and pback pointers to define the
>   location to write more data. On failure, the function ensures that
>   either pptr() == nullptr or pptr() == epptr.

Basically, what this means is that is may resize the buffer appropriately to fit more data, and with gcc this is exactly what is happening. Here is the actually code [take from here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01538_source.html):

```
const __size_type __opt_len = std::max(__size_type(2 * __capacity), __size_type(512));
const __size_type __len = std::min(__opt_len, __max_size);
```

As you can see it either doubles the capacity or sets it to a size of `512` until it hits the maximum size the string buffer can reach.

Comment: [Interesting](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6b7674f7a92b5fbaf0982da0ae262213-803889f054654ad4b92ce24ea171578e).  You win.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Technically it is implementation defined, but on gcc this is the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ does not do any explicit bounds checking, so overflowing memory is possible (and easy to do). If you run your code through a debugger like Valgrind, it will tell you that you are reading uninitialized memory.

Comment: So is this undefined behavior? How can I prevent this from happening? There could be a situation where I don't know the length of the byte array.

Comment: You will have to implement manual error checking in your code. For example to check the length of the string before you put it in the buffer. The website of slibc (https://code.google.com/p/slibc/), which provides an implementation of C11 new bounds-checking, has some nice examples of what can go wrong. They are in C, but the concepts are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Your buffer is still 5 bytes long and doesn't take more byte than allowed, but putting 12 bytes in will "just" perform a write out of boundary that can cause a lot of issue in software programming (crash, UB, data corruption...)

`strlen` may be use to check what you write against the buffer size before copying.